# User avatars are not being served

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-picture

Whatever it is that serves up user avatars has been randomly(?) failing for the past several days. I've checked this on several different browsers. If you go to the "Users" page of any SE site, you'll find that at least half of the avatars are missing. This applies to both user-supplied images as well as the system-generated geometric icons.

Comment: Did you check the URLs of the failing avatars vs those that are not? Are they all coming from the same place (I am guessing it is Gravatar and that it is either failing or your network is having problems accessing it).

Comment: This has been bothering me too. I get `www.gravatar.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` if I open one in another tab. And I am getting this on two separate computers. My own pic is affected...

Comment: Not much we can do about that, @Laurel - you can always upload a picture so issues with gravatar don't affect your avatar.

Comment: @Oded but it affects most user icons. For example, the OP's icon is also affected. I would rather have them all fixed instead of skirting around the problem. I suspect this may be a regional glitch, maybe.

Comment: @Laurel - sure. But what do you expect **us** to do about it? We are not in control of gravatar, their network or DNS servers.

Comment: @Oded: What we expect is that if you're going to use gravatar.com, that you'd be willing to escalate an issue to them. It's making SE look bad.

Comment: @DaveTweed It's not even necessarily an issue with Gravatar per se. Could be any number of things failing, starting with your ISP. Unfortunately, there's not much for us to do here unless one of us can even reproduce the problem and figure out where something fell over.

Comment: @Adam: As a web developer, I understand everything you're saying. But as an end user, I should not need to know or care about how you have chosen to aggregate the various elements that go into an SE web page. It should "just work". If a significant number of users can get everything from SE.com just fine, but not from gravatar.com, that's an issue for SE, even if it can't be reproduced by a developer at a particular location.

Answer (score 2):

[I had this error too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZiNN.png), but I found a solution. I only wish I knew why it was happening in the first place.

I followed the steps [here](http://www.incrediblelab.com/dns-probe-finished-nxdomain-windows/), which means using [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

Here are the steps I followed, with the screenshots.

Right click:

[image: Opened Network & Sharing]

Clicked on the current connection (should be WiFi or LAN), then clicked properties:

[image: Click Properties]

Select IPv4, then click Properties:

[image: Arrows pointing]

Type in new DNS addresses, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are both Google's:

[image: "Use the following DNS"]